# NavBar does not work properly in mobile version

Tags: c#, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a screenshot of my website menu. In my mobile version of the website I am trying to remove the lines between theses four big tabs and make them the same as the Home tab above.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my code of the _LoginPartial.cshtml file

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
        <li>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("index", "App", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "seminarForm",  @class = "navbar-form" } ))
            {    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <a  class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:document.getElementById('seminarForm').submit()">Seminar</a>
                @*@<li>@Html.ActionLink("Seminars", "index", "App")</li> *@
            }
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the 3.x navbar instead of [Bootstrap 4 navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Comment: Do you have the proper css and js loaded in your page? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside the **li<> tag** , which wants to be displayed in the dropdown,
for further references check my plunker.

```
edit like this
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5gvJYTgRcp6WzrN9cIOd?p=preview

Comment: I did , it still does not work. Here is code of my file _LoginPartial.cshtml:

Comment: put in plunker and share the link, i will sort that tomorrow